Cannnot get electron asarUnpack option to work
I have an electron app that needs to be distributed with 2 windows EXE binaries that the app will execute. I followed the pattern described in bundling precompiled binary into electron app to invoke the EXE programs from the resources directory. It works fine in development but I cannot get the packaged/distributed app to leave the 2 EXE files out of the app.asar file. I am using electron-forge to create a windows installer. I have the following in package.json
{
  "name": "CT3680Updater",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CT3680 Updater",
  "main": "js/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "author": "Cabintech Global LLC",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
    "electron": "^30.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
   "build": {
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "resources/win",
        "to": "Resources/bin",  
        "filter": ["**/*"]
      }
    ],
    "asarUnpack": [
      "./Resources/**"
    ]
  }
}**

and forge.config.js
const { FusesPlugin } = require('@electron-forge/plugin-fuses');
const { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } = require('@electron/fuses');

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
    // Fuses are used to enable/disable various Electron functionality
    // at package time, before code signing the application
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
};

This builds a windows-squirrel distributable. When the installer is run the install directory has resources/app.asar, but there is nothing else in the resources directory. Details on how to use the asarUnpack option are sketchy with few actual examples I can find. I tried many combinations of file patterns but still cannot get the EXE files out of the asar archive in the install directory.
